# React-Native: Change badge color in @react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

Can i change the color of the **badge** in material-bottom-tabs? Because it is already red by default and i nedd to change it. If it is possible, how i can do it?

```
...

import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';

...
const MainBottomTab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

...

    <MainBottomTab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      activeColor="#C9C9C9"
      inactiveColor="#4523AF"
      barStyle={styles.menuBotao}>
...
      <MainBottomTab.Screen
        name="Publicações"
        component={PublicacaoNavication}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: '',
          tabBarBadge: notificacoes !== undefined ? notificacoes.length : false, <-- I need to change the color
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => <Icon name={'filing'} color={color} />,
        }}
      />

...

</MainBottomTab.Navigator>

...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do so by overwriting the default theme like this:

```
import { DefaultTheme, Provider as PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';

// Create your custom theme and override the notification color
const MyTheme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    notification: 'blue',
  },
};

// Pass your theme to the PaperProvider wrapping your app
const App = () => {
  return (
    <PaperProvider theme={MyTheme}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        // The rest of your content...
      </NavigationContainer>
    </PaperProvider>
  );
};
// ...
```

Comment: Sorry, but i forgot to say that i am not using NavigationContainer, just only with `const MainBottomTab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();`, is there any chance to do that way?

Comment: If i nest those two (NavigationContainer and MainBottomTab.Navigator) i have to pass this prop `independent={true}` , because i get this error: `Looks like you have nested a 'NavigationContainer' inside another. Normally you need only one container at the root of the app, so this was probably an error. If this was intentional, pass 'independent={true}' explicitely. Note that this will make the child navigators disconnected from the parent and you won't be able to navigate between them.`, then i tried to pass the theme prop togheter and did not work.

Comment: You should have 1 `NavigationContainer` and put it at the top of your component tree. So make sure you're not rendering 2 inside of each other like the error is telling you.

Comment: This is work for changing the tabBarBadge color but the text inside is black by default, how to change that